# Get JavaScript function output from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation, navigator

I have a PHP script that is calculating distances using Google Maps API and the JavaScript geolocation system.

I'd like to get the current user's coordinates in my PHP code, for example:

```
$user_location = array(latitude, longitude);
```

As of now I'm trying something like this:

**location.php:**

```
$contents = file_get_contents('user_loc.html');
if ($contents != "false") {
    $user_location = explode(',', $contents);
}
// Do stuff with coordinates
```

**user_loc.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                function (position) {
                    console.log(position.coords.latitude);
                    document.write(position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);
                }, 
                function (error) {
                    document.write("false");
                }, 
                {
                    timeout: (5 * 1000),
                    maximumAge: (1000 * 60 * 15),
                    enableHighAccuracy: true
                }
            );
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm pretty sure that this is not the best way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to use js to run on client in order to get geolocation, then send it back to server. Or you can just get the geolocation based on the requester's ip, but that may be less reliable.

Comment: file_get_contents would get the string output of the file, not the result you are looking for.  You need to visit the page, and then on the page you could do a POST to location.php with the lat and long and process as needed

Answer (score 0):

The function `document.write` is only a temporary DOM manipulation and is not going to be saved in your file.
The right sequence would be to run the html file, determine the coordinates with javascript and then send them to the server hosting your php file (e.g. via AJAX).

Example with jQuery AJAX:

```
// your code above ...
$.post("location.php", { lat: latitude, lon: longitude }, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

On the server side location.php you could now print that data you received from the html:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

This is called an asynchronous request. When opening the location.php file manually you won't get any data because you didn't pass any. So when the html file gets executed it uses javascript to determine that data and now you got it and just want to send it to the server. To get the server response I implemented a callback function with a `console.log` of the server response so you can check the result.